# How to set initial data in a FormMixin and DetailView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, mixins

I want to create a comment form using generic foreignkey, but a having troubles with getting the initial data for object_id and content_type in the form ?

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user    =   models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type=   models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id   =   models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object=   GenericForeignKey()
    parent=   models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content  =   RichTextField()
    time_stamp  =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Forms.py

```
class CommentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content_type    =   forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    object_id       =   forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    content         =   forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'class':'form-control',
        'cols':'4',
        'rows':'3'
    }))

    class Meta:
        model   =   Comment
        fields  =   ['content','user','object_id', 'content_type']
```

Views.py

```
class SongDetail(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model       =   Song
    form_class  =   CommentsForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('music:obj.get_absolute_url()')

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
class SongDetail(ModelFormMixin, DetailView):
    model       =   Song
    form_class  =   CommentsForm

    def get_initial(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return { 'content_type': obj.content_type, 'object_id': obj.object_id }

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('music:obj.get_absolute_url()')
        
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

FYI, I am using [`ModelFormMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin) instead of `FormMixin`, as it provides save functionality built-in.

Here I am overriding [`get_initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) method to return `content_type` and `object_id` from it. Then these values will be passed to the form and will be loaded as initial value.

Comment: Thanks for your response......
I am using python3.8 and django==3.1.1, and am still having trouble in getting the Content_Type instance